# Not able to access individual data entries in SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have saveinSQL class (extends SQLiteOpenHelper) where in I have defined my database accessing methods. I have created a database in Create class. I want to access the database in Home class. I'm able to get the number of rows in my database in my Home class by which I imply that I am able to access the database. But I am not able to access the data entries in a particular cell of the SQLite table with the help of cursor. My **getHeader** function seems to be faulty. Someone please help me. The part I'm dealing with is in the **onCreate** function of **Home Class**. The error I'm getting is **android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1**

This is my **Home class.** I'm getting error on **temp.header = mydb.getHeader(1);**

```
package com.example.yashubale.mypetitions;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        ArrayList<Petition> ap;
        saveinSQL mydb;

        String a,b,c;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("Dashboard");
        ap = new ArrayList<Petition>();
        mydb = saveinSQL.getInstance(this);
        int numPetitions = mydb.numberOfRows();
    Toast.makeText(this , Integer.toString(numPetitions) ,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Petition temp = new Petition();
    //        temp.header = mydb.getHeader(2);
        temp.header = mydb.getHeader(1);
    //        temp.header = mydb.getHeader(3);
    //        for(int i= 1 ; i <= numPetitions ; i++){
    //
    //           // temp.header = mydb.getHeader(i);
    //            temp.description = mydb.getDescription(i);
    //            temp.people = mydb.getPeople(i);
    //            //ap.add(temp);
    //        }
      //  ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listpetitions);
      //  customeAdapter ca = new customeAdapter(this,ap);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();



    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_create) {
        startCreate(this);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_mypetitions) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
public void startCreate(Context c){
    Intent intent = new Intent(c , Create.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

This is my **saveinSQL class**

```
 package com.example.yashubale.mypetitions;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class saveinSQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

String header = new String();
String descrip = new String();
String people = new String();
Cursor res;
private static saveinSQL mInstance = null;
private Context myctx;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String PETITIONS_TABLE_NAME = "Petitions";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB.db";
public static final String PETITIONS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String PETITIONS_COLUMN_HEADING = "heading";
public static final String PETITIONS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String PETITIONS_COLUMN_PEOPLE = "people";

public saveinSQL(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    myctx = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "create table Petitions" +
                    "(id integer primary key, heading text, description text, people text)"
    );
}

public static synchronized saveinSQL getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new saveinSQL(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Petitions");
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertPetition  (String heading, String description,String people)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("heading", heading);
    contentValues.put("description", description);
    contentValues.put("people", people);
    db.insert("Petitions", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getData(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from Petitions where id="+id+"", null );
    return res;
}




public  String getHeader(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     res = db.rawQuery("select * from Petitions where id=" + id + "", null);
    res.moveToPosition(id);
//        for(int i = 1; i < id; i++){
//            res.moveToNext();
//        }
    header =    res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(saveinSQL.PETITIONS_COLUMN_HEADING));
    res.moveToFirst();
    return header;
}

public String getDescription(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    res = db.rawQuery("select * from Petitions where id=" + id + "", null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    for(int i = 1; i < id; i++){
        res.moveToNext();
    }
     descrip = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(saveinSQL.PETITIONS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION));
    return descrip;
}

public String getPeople(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     res = db.rawQuery("select * from Petitions where id=" + id + "", null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    for(int i = 1; i < id; i++){
        res.moveToNext();
    }
     people = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(saveinSQL.PETITIONS_COLUMN_PEOPLE));
    return people;
}




public int numberOfRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, PETITIONS_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}

public boolean updatePetitiont (Integer id, String heading, String description, String people)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("heading", heading);
    contentValues.put("description", description);
    contentValues.put("people", people);
    db.update("Petitions", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public Integer deletePetition (Integer id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("Petitions",
            "id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllPetitions()
{
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from Petitions", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(PETITIONS_COLUMN_HEADING)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
}
```

This my **Create Class**

```
public class Create extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText mHeadingView;
private EditText mDescriptionView;
saveinSQL mydb = new saveinSQL(this);
EditText headingGet;
EditText descriptionGet;
EditText peopleGet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createpetition);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createPetition();
        }
    });

}

public void createPetition(){
    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;
    mHeadingView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heading);
    mDescriptionView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);
    mHeadingView.setError(null);
    mDescriptionView.setError(null);
    String heading = mHeadingView.getText().toString();
    String description = mDescriptionView.getText().toString();
    if(heading.isEmpty()) {
        mHeadingView.setError("Heading is too short");
        focusView = mHeadingView;
        cancel = true;
    }
    if(description.isEmpty()){
        mDescriptionView.setError("Description is too short");
        focusView = mDescriptionView;
        cancel  = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        focusView.requestFocus();

    }
    else{
        headingGet =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.heading);
        descriptionGet =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);
        peopleGet =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.members);
//            for(int i = 1; i < 5 ; i++){
//                mydb.deletePetition(i);
//            }
        if(mydb.insertPetition(headingGet.getText().toString(), descriptionGet.getText().toString(), peopleGet.getText().toString())){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Petition Added" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: assuming that your table contains unique values for the id column, the query would only return 1 row or none. You should first test whether the query returned any rows by if (res.moveToFirst()) { // retrieve the string value here }

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b The function numberOfRows is working fine, I had added 4 rows (petitons, what I call) in my database. When I called the function from home class, I get the return value of this function as 4, which means that the numberOfRows are 4.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b I have put res.moveToPosition(id) in the if condition, now when I toast it from my Home class it shows nothing. (empty string). That means this function is returning an empty string. But it is still showing correct number of row entries. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = db.rawQuery("select * from Petitions where id=" + id + "", null);
res.moveToPosition(id);
```

The query returns only a single row (because of the WHERE filter), so you cannot move to any position except 0.

Replace the `moveToPosition` with `moveToFirst`.
And there is no need to return any other columns, and you should also handle the case when a row with that ID was not found:

```
res = db.rawQuery("select "+saveinSQL.PETITIONS_COLUMN_HEADING+
                  " from Petitions"+
                  " where id=" + id + "", null);
if (res.moveToFirst())
    header = res.getString(0);
else
    header = "";
```

Please note that there is a [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) that makes it much easier to get the value from a query that returns a single row with a single column:

```
header = DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(db,
                "select "+saveinSQL.PETITIONS_COLUMN_HEADING+
                " from Petitions"+
                " where id=" + id + "", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  String getHeader(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String header = "";
    res = db.rawQuery("select * from Petitions where id=" + id + "", null);
    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
        header = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(saveinSQL.PETITIONS_COLUMN_HEADING));
    }
    return header;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

"create table Petitions" +
                    "(id integer primary key, heading text, description text, people text)"

"create table Petitions(id integer primary key autoincrement,heading text, description text, people text)"

Comment: I did this, but still to no vain. I am not able to access my individual row entries (cell entry of the table), but still when I call function numberOfRows it returns the correct value.

Comment: After modified the need to delete the original application, because before id does not automatically increase So according to the id is not find the corresponding data